# Which is the correct way to test for significant differences between non-numeric data? Which is the correct post-hoc?

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

I'm working with non numeric data that looks something like this:

| Origin | ESBL |
| --- | --- |
| Hospital | ESBL |
| Hospital | Non-ESBL |
| Hospital | ESBL |
| City | ESBL |
| Hospital | Non-ESBL |
| City | ESBL |
| Country | ESBL |
| Hospital | ESBL |

And I want to compare if there is a statistical association between the origin and the variable ESBL.

So far I have tried generating a contingency table in R using:

```
cont_tab<-table(data$Origin, data$ESBL)
```

and the running a chi squared test for independence:

```
chi_test<-chisq.test(cont_tab)
```

After this, I get that there is indeed independency:

```
X-squared = 17.306, df = 2, p-value = 0.0001746
```

But now I want to know which are the combinations that are responsible for this values (ESBL-Hospital, Non-ESBL-Hospital, ESBL-City and so on).

I have tried running multiple Fisher tests:

```
Library(RVAideMemoire)
multifish<-fisher.multcomp(cont_tab)
```

But I don't really get what I want:

```
            ESBL Non-ESBL
  Hospital   46      122
  City       27       21
  Country    56       69
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a better approach for this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think the "final result" you are showing is actually `cont_tab`. When I run your code, `cont_tab` looks like the result you are showing here, whereas `multifish` shows a table of p values for the pairwise comparisons between the different `Origin` values. We can see in it (as expected) that `Hospital` is significantly different from both `City` and `Country`, but there is no significant difference between `City` and `Country`. Can you double check you are looking at `multifish`? What do you get if you just type `fisher.multcomp(cont_tab)` in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "final result" you are showing is actually `cont_tab`. When I run your code, `cont_tab` looks like the result you are showing as being the output from `fisher.multicomp` :

```r
cont_tab <- table(data$Origin, data$ESBL)

cont_tab
#>           
#>            ESBL Non-ESBL
#>   Hospital   46      122
#>   City       27       21
#>   Country    56       69
```

Whereas, if I run `fisher.multcomp` on `cont_tab`, I get:

```r
library(RVAideMemoire)

fisher.multcomp(cont_tab)
#> 
#>         Pairwise comparisons using Fisher's exact test for count data
#> 
#> data:  cont_tab
#> 
#>         Hospital  City
#> City    0.001313     -
#> Country 0.004249 0.234
#> 
#> P value adjustment method: fdr
```

We can see in it (as expected) that `Hospital` is significantly different from both `City` and `Country`, but there is no significant difference between `City` and `Country`.

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data inferred from question**

```r
data <- data.frame(
  ESBL = factor(c(rep(c("ESBL", "Non-ESBL"), times = c(46, 122)),
                  rep(c("ESBL", "Non-ESBL"), times = c(27, 21)),
                  rep(c("ESBL", 'Non-ESBL'), times = c(56, 69)))),
  Origin = factor(rep(c('Hospital', 'City', 'Country'), 
                      times =  c(168, 48, 125)), 
                  c('Hospital', 'City', 'Country')))
```

Comment: Dear Allan,

 Thanks for your help! I was actually looking at the output of the fisher.multcomp but I copied the wrong table in my question. 
So as you say, it is expected from the numbers that the significant difference found by the chi test was due to the hospital samples. Looking at the fisher.multcomp output I get the differences between sources but I would like to know what is the driver of that difference (ESBL or Non-ESBL). Looking at the contingency table, this difference is due to the Non-ESBL but I'm not really understanding how to get a value that shows that.

Thanks!!

Comment: @Sushiroll a Fisher test compares the difference in the _proportion_ of ESBL/non-ESBL, so by definition it is dependent on _both_ ESBL and non-ESBL. If you want to know whether the difference is driven by an increase in non-ESBL or a fall in ESBL, then you need more information. For example, it could be that the Hospital group has a low rate of ESBL, but the population from which the sample was drawn is larger than the others. You may need to look at rates per swab tested or per head of population to know what is "driving" the difference. Contingency tables alone can't tell you that.

Comment: Hey @Allan,

 Thanks for the reply, I should go deeper then and check why this difference is happening. By the way, just to check I'm interpreting things right, what I'm getting with the Chi test is that there are differences in the populations regarding the proportions of ESBL/Non-ESBL and the Fisher is telling me that the population that has a different proportion is those from the hospital when compared to the city and country.
Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ADE-4/ade4-html/discrimin.coa.html for a completely different, academically pristine approach implemented in the R package ade4.
Your variable ESBL would play the role of the class variable in a Discriminant Correspondence Analysis (DCA).

Comment: Dear rwinkel,

  Thanks for the suggestion, right now I'm covered with other things but I will give this approach a shot as soon as I can and I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks Sushiroll. I found this DCA approach interesting because it's relatively new in spite of the fact that this kind of problem comes up frequently. I too am battling with a work project but will try to circle back and apply DCA to this particular data. One thing that helped me implement this with other data was to work the example's dataframes through alongside my own dataframes to constantly confirm mine have the same structure, data types etc.